# How does Xen pause a VM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm, xen

Pause: store VM state in memory

Suspend: store VM state on disk

How does Xen pause an instance? does it just pause the hypervisors processor thats managing the VM using Kill -STOP PID command, or is this done in another way ?

Answer (score 0):

As it can be seen from the following output , the processors managing the VM go into "unknown" state once a vm is paused.

```
[root@server my_vm]# xm vcpu-list my_vm
Name                                ID  VCPU   CPU State   Time(s) CPU Affinity
my_vm                               10     0    16   -b-       6.7 any cpu
my_vm                               10     1    14   -b-       6.8 any cpu
my_vm                               10     2    13   -b-       6.3 any cpu
my_vm                               10     3    22   -b-       5.9 any cpu
[root@server my_vm]# 
[root@server my_vm]# xm pause my_vm
[root@server my_vm]# xm vcpu-list my_vm
Name                                ID  VCPU   CPU State   Time(s) CPU Affinity
my_vm                               10     0     4   ---       6.8 any cpu
my_vm                               10     1    20   ---       6.8 any cpu
my_vm                               10     2    13   ---       6.4 any cpu
my_vm                               10     3     9   ---       5.9 any cpu
```

Also , the xen hypervisor process does not get killed. For a paused vm could still see it running. The process "/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm" runs whether vm is paused/unpaused.

Comment: When you pause a VM, what happens to shared resources? Say I have opened a connection to some remote endpoint, upon unpausing the VM what happens to those connections? I'm assuming they will have failed, and there needs to be a handler that tries to reconnect? What about connections that were transferring data while you paused the VM, what happens to that?

Answer (score 0):

start on pause

```
xl create -p domUConfig
```

running on pause

```
xl pause instantID or instantName
```

unpause domU

```
xl unpause instantID or instantName
```

domU Shutdown

```
xl shutdown instantID or instantName
```

domU Destroy

```
xl destroy instantID or instatName
```

instant check
`xl info`